# What is the equation of a plane passing through a point in R3 in terms of its intercepts with the three axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I saw in a textbook that one equation is $\frac xa + \frac yb + \frac zc = 1, \text{ with} (x,y,z)$ being the point and $a,b,c$ being the intercepts $(a,0,0) (0,b,0) (0,0,c).$

I feel like the reason is very obvious but I just can't think of it.

Comment: Do you have any background in the calculus of vectors?

Comment: A plane will have the form $Ax+By+Cz=D$.  Your equation is of that form so its a plane.  Confirm that all three intercepts solve your equation.  Thus it's the plane passing through all of those points.

Comment: I think you've turned the last fraction $\frac cz$ upside-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to me not well posed. Your title asks for the equation of a plane passing through a point as a function of its intercepts with the axes. It is true that the equation $\dfrac xa + \dfrac yb + \dfrac cz = 1$ in effect passes through points $(a,0,0), (0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$ on the axis which is easily verified but does not pass through a particular point , say by $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. In that case the answer is deduced as follows
$$\begin{cases}\dfrac xa + \dfrac yb + \dfrac cz = 1\\\dfrac {x_0}{a} + \dfrac {y_0}{b} + \dfrac {c_0}{z}=1\end{cases}\Rightarrow\color{red}{\dfrac{x-x_0}{a}+\dfrac{y-y_0}{b}+\dfrac{z-z_0}{c}=0}$$ The red equation is the answer to your title where obviously $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is the considered particular point.